# No se abre el teclado para introducir texto al dar click en searchbox

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

Codigo de c#

```
SearchBar searchBar = new SearchBar()
            {
                Placeholder = "Introducir Texto",
                Keyboard=Keyboard.Text
                
            };
            searchBar.TextChanged += OnTextChanged;
```

es visible en la app pero al dar click solo parpadea la barra | y se oculta rapido y no abre el teclado para introducir texto a buscar.

nota: lo estoy compilando para android 9

codigo completo

```
var searchBarTallerAseg = new StackLayout() { Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,ClassId="stackBar" };
            SearchBar searchBar = new SearchBar()
            {
                Placeholder = "Introducir Texto",
                Keyboard=Keyboard.Text,
                WidthRequest=-1,
                FontSize = 15,
                HorizontalOptions =LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand,
                ClassId = "VEH(" + vehiculoAsegurado.IdVehiculo.ToString() + "(taller",
                IsEnabled=true,
                IsVisible=true
                

            };
            searchBar.TextChanged += OnTextChanged;
            
            searchBarTallerAseg.Children.Add(searchBar);
            lstviewcell.Add(new ViewCell() { View = searchBarTallerAseg });
            searchBar.Focus();
```

Comment: agrega lo que realiza OnTextChanged

Comment: Ya agregue el codigo, gracias por responder

Comment: el detalle es que si doy click a un lado y deslizo el dedo si abre el teclado y si hace la busqueda, el problema es que quiere que abra el teclado justo donde esta el texto del input